# Word VBA - Find text between delimiters and convert to lower case

Tags: regex, vba, replace, find

I would like to find text which is between the < and > characters, and then turn any found text into "normal" case, where first letter of word is capitalized. Here is what I have thus far:

```
Function findTextBetweenCarots() As String

Dim strText As String

With Selection
    .Find.Text = "<"  ' what about <[^0-9]+>  ?
    .Find.Forward = True
    .Find.Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With

Selection.Find.Execute


 ' Application.Selection. ' how do I get the text between the other ">"?
    findCarotSymb = Application.Selection.Text

End Function
```

Or, is there a better way of doing this? I also approached the problem using the VBScript Regex 5.5 library, which worked on simple documents, but not on certain documents with complex tables. For example, trying to just bold the text (for simplicity):

```
 Sub BoldUpperCaseWords()

  Dim regEx, Match, Matches
  Dim rngRange As Range

  Set regEx = New RegExp
  regEx.Pattern = "<[^0-9]+>"
  regEx.IgnoreCase = False
  regEx.Global = True

  Set Matches = regEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range.Text)

  For Each Match In Matches

     ActiveDocument.Range(Match.FirstIndex, Match.FirstIndex + Len(Match.Value)).Bold = True

  Next

End Sub
```

would not work in a document with tables. In fact, it would not even bold the correct text (the text between the `<>`. This leads me to believe I have a broader issue here that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not test your code but try this regex

```
regEx.Pattern = "<[^0-9<>]+>"
```

Your regex would match in `"<foo><bar>"` the whole string.
The above regex will match only the `<foo>`, then the `<bar>` and so on.

Comment: I get the same result. There is something particular about the documents I am using this on. They are 4 column tables, if that helps. The most I can do is provide a screenshot of a sample document in my next edit.

Comment: print `ActiveDocument.Range.Text` to see if it contains all the text. Also check if the `regEx` properties handle multi-line text. (if possible, try to iterate table's rows and apply regex to each column)